# Continue with Id order values after delete some rows

Tags: sql

I accidentally deleted some rows from a table, it's just 4 rows, but now when I try to insert the same values again the Id values are different, it's like it's remembering the Id values that had the rows I deleted before and now every time I insert a row the value generated for Id is not the next to the existent sequence... For example:

```
Id   Name 
1    Peter
2    Luis
3    Charles
4    John
```

Let's say I deleted rows with Name value Peter, Luis, Charles and John. When I try to insert the same names again it inserts them but with a different Id..

```
Id   Name
1    Peter
5    Luis
6    Charles
7    John
```

I can not change the Identity value manually to the old values.. Which is the best solution in this case?

Comment: There is no problem.  So, just ignore the gaps.  This is how `identity` columns work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting identity_insert to on and entering the Ids manually with the names and then changed the table back to how it was with identity_insert off

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that auto-incrementing Id's don't automatically reset. This is by design, as you may have the same values references in other tables, which you may not want to delete (although it creates orphaned rows).

The method of resetting the auto-incrementing value differs between databases. For instance, in MySQL, you can run:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable SET AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you AUTOINCREMENT the Primary Key then you can't change the sequence with which you have started.Even if you insert the same name again it does not matter.It will continue from the next number with which it previously ended.
But if you want to give it a number then don't AUTOINCREMENT it,INSERT primary key value like other values you have inserted in the table.